# Identifying the string instrument used

Tags: sheet-music, violin, string-instruments, viola

I’m going to start learning to play a string instrument but I couldn’t choose between a violin or a viola.

Recently I’ve been listening to an anime instrumental music and I have fell in love with it and was wondering if anyone could help me to identify the string instrument that was used?

The whole music is beautifully made but I’m having a hard time identifying the string instrument.

Comment: Is there a particular part of the music you mean? The music sounds like it contains a whole string section: many string instruments playing together, potentially  including violins, violas, cellos, and basses.

Comment: @topomorto beginning from 0:26 the dominant instrument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary instruments in the main theme (0:26 as you said) are the violin section. You can tell it's violin and not viola because of the timbre of the F natural at 0:40. Hope this helps.